# jquery - How to best update a text file on change

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery script on a page that's coming together, thanks to code and people here, and i'm stuck at a point where I need to call a part of a larger function.  I'm not sure how to break into multiple functions i think.  Everything runs correctly when i create dynamic input fields and it totals up some amount fields into a totals box, but if i don't create new input boxes then it don't get that part i need to total up these inputs.  Here is a sample of what i have so far with a comment in the code where i need help:

[http://jsfiddle.net/A3dnr/](http://jsfiddle.net/A3dnr/2/)

```
// ** Need help to call just this part when text is entered/changed in any of the 'amount' fields **
   var total = 0;
    $('input[name^="Amount"]').each(function () {
        total += parseInt(this.value, 10) || 0;
        if (this.value.length === 0) this.value = 0;
    });
    $('#Totals').val(total);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code block that calculates the totals is inside click handler for *add new row* button so it'll only be called when this button is pressed. You need to move it outside of the click handler. [Check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A3dnr/4/). I've converted it to a function like following

```
        function updateTheTotal(){
           var total = 0;
           $('input.Amount').each(function () {
              total += parseInt(this.value, 10) || 0;
              if (this.value.length === 0) this.value = 0;
           });
           $('#Totals').val(total);
        }
```

and it gets called on *keyup* of all amount fields

```
$('.Amount').on('keyup', updateTheTotal);
```

**Note:** your code is candidate for optimization by caching selectors

Comment: This is exactly what i was striving for.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an event.  First add a class of 'amount' on every amount input.  Then add something like this:

```
$('table').on('change', '.amount', function() {
  var amount = 0;
  $('.amount').each(function() {
    amount =+ this.value;
  })
  $('#Totals').val(amount);
})
```

Also, add type="number" to your amount inputs as well.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function to perform the total, and call it in your existing click event and in a new change event bound on fields change.

```
function updateTotal()
{
    var total = 0;
    $('input[name^="Amount"]').change(function () {
        total += parseInt(this.value, 10) || 0;
        if (this.value.length === 0) this.value = 0;
    });
    $('#Totals').val(total);        
}

$('body').on('change','input[name^="Amount"]',function () {
    updateTotal();
});
```